Azure devops pipelines to GitHub Release
Hi have the following release task set up for github org release,
- task: GitHubRelease@1
            inputs:
              gitHubConnection: '(GH) Prod-RW-Releases'
              repositoryName: 'Azure/testrepository'
              action: 'create'
              target: '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
              tagSource: 'userSpecifiedTag'
              tag: 'v1.0.2-prerelease'
              title: 'v$(Build.BuildNumber)'
              assets: '$(REPOROOT)/src/**'
              addChangeLog: false
              isPreRelease: true

I have the repository in azure devops pipeline, no matter whatever i try i keep getting 422 error for one reason or another.

Tag_Name is not valid, so many times this issue came up, finally i was able to resolve it by creating a release and tagging it with a tagname and gave same tagname to my build pipeline. But somehow i feel there can be a better way to do this thing. I am not even sure if i am doing the right thing.

This is the current error message which i am hustling with right now. {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"Release","code":"invalid","field":"target_commitish"}],"documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/releases/releases#create-a-release","status":"422"}}


We have an urgent GA release, need to do a global publish for our tools.
Worst case plan B is to move all the code to GitHub repository and take things from there.

By I have the repository in azure devops pipeline, do you mean your pipeline referenced the .yml definition file in Azure Repos rather than the release's GitHub Repo?

The One Branch build pipeline, I created a GitHub service connection to deploy from the azure DevOps pipeline to GitHub service connection. So its from the azure devops one branch .yml file which has the githubrelease task to release things to git hub organization.

An Azure DevOps pipeline references the .yml definition file from the repo provider. When you created this pipeline, you selected Azure Repo or GitHub repo? In another word, your pipeline definition file is located in Azure Repo or GitHub repo?

The Pipeline definition file is located in Azure Repo.

So you have both Azure Repo and GitHub repo. May I know how they share the same base to create a new tag?

Do you have any microsoft alias you can message me personally, i can ping you on teams.

we have code with git kind of setup with azure devops. They don't share any base. I think thats where the problem is some commit mismatch error is also happening, i tried multiple things. Every single time i got 422 error in the pipeline.

Based on the update, we discussed the relationship between your GitHub repository and the Azure Repo where the .yml pipeline definition file resided. For further investigation, I imported the code from my GitHub testrepository into Azure Repos and created a pipeline with GitHubRelease@1 task. The issue could be still reproduced if there was no corresponding commit SHA (target: '$(Build.SourceVersion)') in the target GitHub repo. This appears to be the expected behavior when there is no matching commit SHA, as the pipeline attempts to create a Git tag for the GitHub repo.


Azure DevOps supports pipelines that reference definition files from a GitHub repository. I recommend using this method to create GitHub tags and releases directly from your pipeline. Given that there is no shared commit history between your GitHub repository and Azure Repo, performing a force push to the GitHub repository is not advisable.

Hey Alvin, thanks for working on this issue man, I appreciate it. How did you make sure the commit ids match? I didn't get that part, also how did you create tag in the git hub release from azure devops pipeline, i couldn't find any easy way to do that from the web, please elaborate more on that one.

Hi Ashutosh, Thank you a lot for your sharing and reaching out. Per your query on how to make sure the commit ids of the GitHub repo and the Azure Repo match with each other, I imported the GitHub repo in Azure Repos. Hence, from the screenshot in the answer, we could see they share a common version of code with the id of 1f3210ec.

The pipeline generated from Azure Repo only succeeded to tag and release that specific version of code because it also existed in the GitHub repo. With new commits pushed to Azure Repo while GitHub repo didn't have those commits, the pipeline failed. We could also try to push those commits to remote GitHub repo but it required the repos shared a same base. However, I guess it may not be applicable for your based on the discussions. And a force push could change the commit history.

Therefore, I suggest creating pipelines that reference definition files from a GitHub repository directly, so that the pipeline can always checkout code from GitHub repo to make sure the expected version of code exists for git tag.

Could you please elaborate the steps how to do that?

Create a readme.md file in github repository, currently our github repository has some basic files no code no pipeline .yml file nothing else.
How to sync up that readme.md file in azure devops? And how to match the commit ids?


Please also vote my question as a valid one. It will help me get better traction. Thank you  much for all your help and support.

Actually, I generated the azure-pipelines.yml file in the GitHub repo before importing it to Azure Repos. Here is the document on how to import a repo. Then you can create a pipeline with an Existing YAML definition in the imported Azure Repo. You mentioned your Azure Rep and GitHub repo didn't share any base, but if you would like to push commits to the GitHub repo, why not create a pipeline from the GitHub repo directly?
